# Redirect root but not subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect just the root of my site www.example.com to www.example2.com
but not the subfolders www.example.com/subfolder !
Is it possible?

E.G.
the following rule redirect all my site:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example2.com
```

Answer (score 8):

To redirect just the root, you can use the following

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://example2.com/
```